# Waiting for one event handler before executing another one

Tags: javascript, dom-events, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm writing a Firefox browser extension, and I'm stuck on how to wait for a content script to load before sending a message from the background script.
This is the sequence I'm trying to achieve:

1. User clicks context menu item (click handler is in background script)
2. Background script creates new tab
3. Content script loads fully in new tab
4. Background script sends message (with data) to content script
5. Content script uses data

Obviously, the content script needs to be loaded for step 4 to work; otherwise, the message doesn't get received.

I looked at previous similar questions, but most of the answers are incorrect (they wrap the event listener methods in a Promise, which either results in too many listeners or too few Promises), or they seem not-applicable to my scenario (those answers get around the question entirely by putting one callback inside the other; that wouldn't work here).

What I did try so far was to have the content script send a message when it's ready, and that works, but I'm still not sure how to have the click handler (from step 1) wait for a message from the content script (hypothetical step 3.5).
I assume I'd have to define the message handler outside the click handler, as far as I know, unless there's a way to receive the message inside the click handler.

Here's my current code as a minimal working example:

`background.js`:

```
let ports = {
    '1': null,
    '2': null
};

xyz = () => { /*...*/ }
tabHasLoaded = () => { /*...*/ }

browser.runtime.onConnect.addListener(connectHandler);
connectHandler = (p) => {
    ports[p.name] = p;
    switch (p.name) {
        case '1':
            ports['1'].addListener(xyz);
            break;
        case '2':
            ports['2'].addListener(tabHasLoaded);
            break;
    }
};

browser.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener((info, tab) => {
    let data, uri;
    //...
    browser.tabs.create({
        url: uri
    }).then((tab) => {
        // need to wait for tabHasLoaded() to get called
        ports['2'].postMessage({
            msg: data
        })
    });
});
```

`1.js` (content script for something else):

```
let myPort = browser.runtime.connect({
    name: '1'
});
document.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    myPort.postMessage({
        msg: e.target.id
    });
});
```

`2.js` (content script for new tab, after clicking context menu):

```
let myPort = browser.runtime.connect({
    name: '2'
});
myPort.postMessage({
    msg: "READY" // tabHasLoaded() should now get called in background.js
});
myPort.onMessage.addListener((msg) => {
    // waiting for background.js to send me data
});
```

Is there an ideal way to handle this?

Comment: Is your communication 2-way? If so content script should send a signal to background says I'm ready then your background can send the data.
Try to isolate your issue with another project and test it there, or then maybe you can share it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i still think promises are the way to go...

### update

change code to use your MWE... please note that this is untested/not-optimized code just to outline the idea... it should look something like this:

`background.js`

```
let ports = {
    '1': null,
    '2': null
};

xyz = () => { /*...*/ }

browser.runtime.onConnect.addListener(connectHandler);
connectHandler = (p) => {
    ports[p.name] = p;
    switch (p.name) {
        case '1':
            ports['1'].addListener(xyz);
            break;
    }
};

browser.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(async (info, tab) => {
    let data, uri;
    //...
    const tab = await LoadAndWaitForPort2(uri)
    ports['2'].postMessage({msg: data})
});

function LoadAndWaitForPort2(uri){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
    const tab
    const tabHasLoaded = (evt) => {
      if(evt.data.msg === "READY"){
        ports['2'].removeListener(tabHasLoaded)
        resolve(tab)
      } else {
        reject("error!")
      }   
    }
    ports['2'].addListener(tabHasLoaded)
    tab = await browser.tabs.create({url: uri})
  })
}
```

`2.js`

```
let myPort = browser.runtime.connect({
    name: '2'
});
myPort.postMessage({
    msg: "READY" // tabHasLoaded() should now get called in background.js
});
myPort.onMessage.addListener((msg) => {
    // waiting for background.js to send me data
});
```

Comment: async/await *and* promises; didn't think of that. also forgot you can remove listeners. I think I'm struggling with the messaging as well; I have other content scripts, so I've updated my question with a MWE.

Comment: For example, I don't see how I can add the message listener inside `loadTab()` (the equivalent of the `then()` of my `browser.tabs.create()`), since I have to listen from messages from other places as well